# How do I implement onSavedInstanceState() without onPostCreate()?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to implement the `onSavedInstanceState()` method to save an activity state.

Whenever I try to override Android Studio selects the `onPostCreate()` method for me, which takes the `savedInstanceState` bundle as an argument.

Is it possible to achieve this with `android.support.v7.AppCompatActivity` or must I use the `onPostCreate()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Note the time used for the word "Save**d**", that is why `onPostCreate`, which has an `onSavedInstanceState` parameter, is suggested.

Useful tip: To easily get an exhaustive list of available overridable methods, you can use the `CTRL+O` shortcut in the editor.